# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Array, got Object

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I'm new to vuejs and trying to use the buefy library.

Error :

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Array, got  Object

```
<template>
    <b-table :data="data" :columns="columns"></b-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: this.data,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'name',
                        label: 'Name',
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
            .get('/test')
            .then(
                response => (this.data = response)
            )
        }
    }

</script>
```

The json content:

```
[{"name":"test"}]
```

What did I miss? Thx :)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Got it!

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: [],
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'name',
                        label: 'Name',
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
            .get('/test')
            .then(
                response => (this.data = response.data)
            )
        }
    }

</script>
```

Thx :)

Answer (score 8):

The declaration of  data property should be as below:

```
 data: []
```

Updated code:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data: [],
            columns: [
                {
                    field: 'name',
                    label: 'Name',
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
        .get('/test')
        .then(
            response => (this.data = response)
        )
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see Buefy doc here(https://buefy.org/documentation/table#api-view), Table component expecting data as an Array of Objects.

Axios returns the response in detail, you're assigning `response` to `this.data` and which object, that's causing this error. So your data will be coming in as `response.data`

```
data() {
  return { data: []}
}

async mounted() {
    try {
       const { data } = await axios.get('/test')
       this.data = data
    } catch(err) {
       console.err(err)
    }

}
```

In case, if anyone wonders, how to declare a prop with multiple types. Here's an example.

```
...
props: {
  value: {
    type: String | Number | Boolean | Object, or [Number, String, Object]
    default: ''
  }
}
```